# Statsmodel ExponentialSmoothing predicts straight line?

Tags: statsmodels, smoothing, exponential, holtwinters

I have some data I'm trying to fit an `ExponentialSmoothing` on:

```
fit1 = ExponentialSmoothing(df1, trend='add').fit()
```

For some reason the prediction will just predict a straight line:

```
plt.figure(figsize = [15, 5])
plt.plot(fit1.fittedvalues)
plt.plot(fit1.forecast(5000))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Why can this happen? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The model you have selected (exponential smoothing with a trend term) can only produce two types of forecasts:

1. A straight line that is trending up or down (if there is an upwards or downwards trend in your data)
2. A horizonal line (if the trend is estimated to be zero)

Although your data has irregular explosive behavior, it does not overall have a trend in it. To me, it seems reasonable that the trend term would be estimated to be zero, and so the forecast is a straight line.

If you want to model those irregular explosive periods, you would need a more complicated model.